# MySQL insert (composite?) row from totals of columns in multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables of values I need to generate totals for at the end of each day, and need to generate a monthly report with them. My current idea is to make a table for storing the daily totals, but I can't seem to work out how to create a row from these individual queries. Some of these totals require where statements for things like sorting into age ranges.

I have been wracking my brain over how to best do this, but it's been a while since I worked with SQL. Everything I've found here or in the MySQL documentation either doesn't work for MySQL/MariaDB, or doesn't match what I need to do.

Comment: why  you not try with a View, on a view you can make computed columns and with the clausule whre you can filter

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you're talking about. Are you suggesting I use a View Table? How should I go about using it?

Comment: you can use UNION, FOR EXAMPLE: CREATE VIEW MYVIEW AS SELECT sum(mycolumn) as total from table1 where filtercolun= myfilter UNION select sum(secondcolumn) as total from table2 where otherfiltercolumn = myfilter3;, then run : select * from MYVIEW where total>10;

Comment: Well, after taking a long look at how the database was setup and how much time I have left to work on it, I decided against a single total table for everything and opted for separate total tables that really only get accessed once a day outside of operating hours. I'll continue trying your suggestions though for a revised version later.